# Updating a relation between two Entity Framework entities?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have two related Entity Framework 6 classes in my data layer.

```
public class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual SalesStatus SalesStatus { get; set; }
}

public class SalesStatus
{
    public SalesStatus()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderVM
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public SalesStatus SalesStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Automapper to map these to my view models and back again.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderVM>()
    .MaxDepth(4)
    .ReverseMap();
```

The status entity is used to populate a drop down list.

In my method I am taking the selected value and trying to update the order record to the new selected status.

```
 private bool SaveOrderToDb(OrderVM orderVM)
 {
     using (var db = new MyContext())
     {                
         var order = AutomapperConfig.MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper().Map<OrderVM, Order>(orderVM);
         order.SalesStatus = db.SalesStatuses.Find(Convert.ToInt16(orderVM.SalesStatusSelectedValue));
         db.Set<Order>().AddOrUpdate(order);
         db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return true;
}
```

This does not update the relationship in the database. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Because `AddOrUpdate` marks as `Added` (including child entities) or as `Modified` (which only affects the root entity, `order` in this case).

Comment: did you found a solution to this yet?